# svn checkout to deploy via shell

Tags: shell, svn, deployment, export, svn-checkout

I have the following problem. I need to organize automatic upload to deploy server from svn repository, but with some feautures.
There is how I wrote it:

```
# $1 - project; $2 - version (optional)
#   rm -rf $projectDir
if [ "$2" == '' ]; then
    svn export $trunk $projectDir --force >> $log
    version=`svn info $trunk | grep Revision | awk '{print$2}'`
    svn copy $trunk $tags/$version -m "created while uploading last version of $1"
    echo "New stable version #$version of $1 is created
    Uploading to last version is completed successfully"
else
    version=$2
    svn export $tags/$version/ $projectDir --force >> $log
    echo "Revert to version #$version is completed successfully"
fi

echo $version > $projectDir/version

chown -R $1:$1 $projectDir
```

But svn export  doesn't delete deleted via svn files, so I need to clean directory before export every time. It's not good.
Before this, I work with checkout for deploy like this:

```
svn co $trunk >> $log
cp -ruf trunk/* $projectDir
svn info $trunk | grep Revision > $projectDir/version
chown -R $project:$project $projectDir
echo "uploading finished"
```

This work very well and very very faster (it changes only changed files) than the export, but:

1. without automatic tag creating;
2. without opportunity for nice reverting.

In my last script co doesn't work, because it trying to checkout in one directory from different repository directories (trunk/some tag), which isn't real.

So, question:

1. Can I relocate project before checkout?
2. Can I find the diff with co version and existing version before export?
3. What can I do with diff result? (remove unneeded files after export?)

Thanks in advance.

Comment: Shell lays in the project server, but svn server is external.

Answer (score 0, accepted):

For the basis for the solution was taken following code:

It's simpler and fully solves the problem as for me.

```
if [ "$2" == '' ]; then
    version=`svn info ${trunk} | grep Revision | awk '{print$2}'`
    if [ `cat ${projectWWW}/version` == "${version}" ]; then
        resultMessage="Project is up to date"
    else
        svn co ${trunk} ${projectRoot}/co >> ${log}
        cp -ruf ${projectRoot}/co/ ${projectRoot}/releases/${version}
        chown -R $1:$1 ${projectRoot}/releases/${version}
        resultMessage="New stable version #$version of $1 is created
        Uploading to last version is completed successfully"
   fi
else
    version=$2
    resultMessage="Revert to version #$version is completed successfully"
fi

ln -s ${projectRoot}/releases/${version} ${projectWWW}
echo ${version} > ${projectWWW}/version
echo ${resultMessage} >> ${log}
```

Answer (score 1):

Have you evaluated [Capistrano](https://github.com/capistrano/capistrano/wiki/Documentation-v2.x)? It can do a lot of what you're trying to achieve.

Comment: I'm newbee in Capistrano and not familiar with Ruby, but it not seems too difficult.  
But do I need to use so huge tool for simple tasks?  
I mean, that the Capistrano don't do any other actions that do I.  
>Each time you deploy, a new directory will be created under the “releases” directory, and the new version placed there. Then, the “current” symbolic link will be updated to point to that directory.  
So, it willn't work faster, because it uploads whole project each time in different folder, which I can do the same way with symlinks.

Comment: All that I need in this case, that check if directory exists and export if not. After that only change symlinks source.
But is it simplest way?

Comment: In addition, there is another moment - export will do the commit, even if files don't changed from last export. This make opportunity to create an infinite number of duplicate versions. Checkout is ideal in all for deploy, but I have described my problem above.

Comment: I'am corrected my algorhytm and got the next: [pastebin](http://pastebin.com/q2sybjYS). What do you think about it?